# Responsive box with border lines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make this exact box with borders lines. you can see after H2 there is new border line and then a paragraph. Please tell me how do I make this? as when I do it with `border-bottom:1px solid` it just makes a lines but doesn't touch the edges of the main border. here I am attaching the image so you can better understand this here you can see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl7vQ.jpg)

my code

```
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" id="house">
            <h3 class="text">Our house packages include:</h3>

            <ul class="lead text" id="list">
            <li>Standard site costs (based on 500mm fall to site & ‘M’ Class slab)</li>
            <li>Rainwater Tank or connection to recycled water where available.</li>
            <li>Concrete driveway (up to 55sqm)</li>
            <li>Tiled Front Porch</li>
            <li> Internal Floor Coverings</li>
            <li> 5+ star gas instantaneous HWS</li>
            <li>Wall & Ceiling insulation</li>
            <li>‘Classic’ range of inclusions</li>
            </ul>
             <img src="images/landing.jpg" alt="landing Image">
<p class="note">NB. Please note that all packages are subject to developer and/or council and statutory authorities’ approvals.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#house {
border: 1px solid black;
background:white;
}

#house h3 {
border-bottom:1px solid;
font-size:28px;
font-weight:bold;
margin:10px;
}

#list {
font-size:15px;
margin:15px;
padding:15px;
position:relative;
right:20px;
text-align:left;

}

#house img {
width:40%;
position:relative;
left:500px;
bottom:260px;
}
```

please tell me how do I make border lines after heading and after list. please take a look into image. It should be responsive.

thank you all

Comment: Can you use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

Comment: if you can fix up code. I will really appreciate that Sir

Comment: anyone to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is missing one div tag on the top, so I'm not able to debug. :/

But this is how I'd solve it if I had to do the same thing:

```
<style>

    html { 
        background: #EEE;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 0;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 40px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color: #AAA;
        font-family: calibri;
    }

    .box{
        background: #FFF;
        border: 2px solid #DDD;
        width: 80%; /*SPECIFY WIDTH HERE*/
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .heading {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD;
        width: 100%; 
        padding: 20px; 
        text-size: 30px;
        font-size: 30px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .content {
        border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px; 
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .footer {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px; 
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .myList {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    li {
        margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .myImg {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .houseImg {
        width: 300px;

    }

</style>

    <div class='box'>
        <div class='heading'>
        Our house packages include:
        </div>

        <div class='content'>
            <div class='myList'>
                 <ul class="lead text" id="list">
                    <li>Standard site costs (based on 500mm fall to site & 'M' Class slab)</li>
                    <li>Rainwater Tank or connection to recycled water where available.</li>
                    <li>Concrete driveway (up to 55sqm)</li>
                    <li>Tiled Front Porch</li>
                    <li> Internal Floor Coverings</li>
                    <li> 5+ star gas instantaneous HWS</li>
                    <li>Wall & Ceiling insulation</li>
                    <li>'Classic' range of inclusions</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class='myImg'>
                <img src='http://www.simplyeleganthomedesigns.com/hudson%20cottage%20FL.jpg' class='houseImg'>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='footer'>
            Some Footer text here
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason `h3` is not working the way you want is because you assigned it a `margin: 10px;` This is going to push the `h3` border `10px` away from its parent on all sides. If you don't assign it a `margin`, `border-bottom` will work fine.

It may be good practice for you to add borders to all elements so you can see how each css rule affects an elements box.

Refer to box model for further information

[W3C Box Model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

[MDN Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model)

Answer (score 0):

1- the border is inside the margin that's [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLwgZ.png) why there is spaces . 
try use the padding for h3

```
padding: 20px;
```

I fix the list for you as well . 
check 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gg8mat4q/1/)